# Strip random <br> tags from end of a string

Tags: c#

I have HTML that is coming from a third party source.

I need to remove all trailing whitespace and line-breaks at the end of a long string, which itself contains `<br>` tags that I need.

For example, the text could be:

`This is some text<br>The End<br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br><br><br>`

I need to remove all those trailing `<br>` tags, some with random white-space between them, others not, while preserving the innner `<br>`.

What is the best way to accomplish this in C# where I have it in a `string`?

I'm leaning towards a `regex` but I can't seem to get the right one that handles only the tail-end of the string.

Comment: if this line is in a string, you could use Regex

Comment: I edited my post right after I sent it to mention that I could use a regex but was unable to come up with one.

Comment: IMO it'd be easier to just see if the line ends with `<br>`, and if so, remove it.  Then trim the end of the string, and repeat.

Comment: Search for this: `^(.*)<br>\r?$` Replace with `$1`.  Try it here:  http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: `while (input.TrimEnd().EndsWith("<br>")) input = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("<br>")).TrimEnd();`

Comment: @Patrick Click on the table link at the bottom of the page.  It'll show the replacement text, which is correct.  However, on reading your question more carefully, this should help with random whitespace:  `^(.*)<br>\s*\r?$`

Comment: @RufusL That works.  Thanks.

Comment: NM.  I misunderstood what you were looking to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your line is in a string (you don't need to parse html), using Regex:

```
string input = @"This is some text<br>The End<br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br><br><br>";
var output = Regex.Replace(input,@"(\<br\>\s?)+$",@"<br>");

//Result:
//This is some text<br>The End<br>
```